# Laravel 5.4 Broadcast Error

Tags: laravel, broadcast, pusher, laravel-events

I try to fire the event

```
 public function index()
{
    event(new MessageSent("HELLO"));
    return view('home');
}
```

and got this error 
[image]

> in PusherBroadcaster.php (line 106) at
>   PusherBroadcaster->broadcast(array(object(PrivateChannel)),
>   'App\Events\MessageSent', array('message' => 'HELLO', 'socket' =>
>   null)) in BroadcastEvent.php (line 49)

- package pusher-php-server was added
- .ENV variables added
- in config/broadcasting added app_id, key, secret
- uncomment BroadcastServiceProvider

What's wrong? Help pls

Comment: Which version of Laravel?

Comment: @ka_lin Laravel 5.4

Comment: In your `composer.json` which version do you have for the `pusher/pusher-php-server` library?

Comment: "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^3.0"

Comment: Try with version 2.0

Comment: ..same error(((

Answer (score 0):

Have you set Pusher to be your Broadcast Driver under your .env?

Answer (score 0):

i am a bit late, however, I have encountered the same error 
mine was in the broadcastWith() in the created event which was as follows:

```
return response()->json([
    'message' => 'hello',
]);
```

I changed my broadcastWith() function to return the message as an array which fixed the error

```
public function broadcastWith()
{
    return ['message' => 'hello'];
}
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem on localhost but everything's well on public server. Then I try to change `"encrypted" => false`. Hope you enjoy it. Cheers :)